# OpenGL C++, Textures Suddenly Black After Being Working For Days

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glfw, glew

Open GL 3.3

My textures suddenly became black after working for many days
Pretty much all the posts that had a similiar issue were about
incorrect or absent use of `glTexParameteri` or **incorrect texture loading** but i seem to be doing everything correctly regarding that,
the vector containing the data is 1024 bytes (16 pixels x 16 pixels x 4 bytes) so that's good,
after the issue arose i made a test texture just to make shure everything about that was right.
also saw that many posts issues were **incomplete texture** but here im using `glTexImage2D` passing the data so the texture has to be complete, also am **not creating mipmaps**, i disabled them for testing. Altough they were on and working before this bug.

Also im calling glGetError quite frequently and there are no errors

Here is the **texture creation** code:

```
unsigned int testTexture;
unsigned long w, h;
std::vector<byte> data;
std::vector<byte> img;
loadFile(data, "./assets/textures/blocks/brick.png");
decodePNG(img, w, h, &data[0], data.size());
glGenTextures(1, &testTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, testTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA8,w,h,0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&img[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
data.clear();
img.clear();
```

And here is where i setup my **Uniforms**:

```
glUseProgram(worldShaderProgram);
glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(worldShaderProgram, "time"), gameTime);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(worldShaderProgram, "MVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, &TheMatrix[0][0]);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(worldShaderProgram, "texAtlas"), testTexture);
glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(worldShaderProgram, "texMult"), 16.0f / 256.0f);
glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(worldShaderProgram, "fogColor"), fogColor.r, fogColor.g, fogColor.b, fogColor.a);
```

Also Here Is The **Fragment Shader**

```
#version 330

in vec4 tex_color;
in vec2 tex_coord;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D texAtlas;
uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform vec4 fogColor;

const float fogStart = 0.999f;
const float fogEnd = 0.9991f;
const float fogMult = 1.0f / (fogEnd - fogStart);

void main() {
    if (gl_FragCoord.z >= fogEnd)
        discard;

    //color = vec4(tex_coord.x,tex_coord.y,0.0f,1.0f) * tex_color; // This Line Does What Its Supposed To
    color = texture(texAtlas,tex_coord) * tex_color; // This One Does Not

    if (gl_FragCoord.z >= fogStart)
        color = mix(color,fogColor,(gl_FragCoord.z - fogStart) * fogMult);
}
```

If i use this line `color = vec4(tex_coord.x,tex_coord.y,0.0f,1.0f) * tex_color;`

Instead of this line `color = texture(texAtlas,tex_coord) * tex_color;`

To show the coord from witch it would be getting its color from the texture, the result is what you would expect: (*Currenlty only testing it with the top faces*)

[Image Link Cause I Cant Do Images But Please Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96ekf.png)

That Proves That The Vertex Shader Is Working Corretly
(*The **sampler2D** is obtained from a uniform at the fragment shader*)

Main Loop **Rendering Code**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures.textureId);
glUseProgram(worldShaderProgram);
wm.render();
// wm.render() calls lots of meshes to render themselves
// just wanted to point out each one of them has their own
// vertex arry buffer, vertex buffer, and index buffer
// to render i bind the vertex array buffer with glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayBuffer);
// then i call glDrawElements();
```

Also here is the OpenGL Initialization Code

```
if (!glfwInit()) // Initialize the library
    return -1;

window = glfwCreateWindow(wndSize.width, wndSize.height, "Minecraft", NULL, NULL);

if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // Make the window's context current
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window,resiseEvent);

glfwSwapInterval(1);

if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    return -1;

glClearColor(fogColor.r, fogColor.g, fogColor.b, fogColor.a);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enable depth testing for z-culling
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); // Orientation Culling
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);    // Set the type of depth-test (<=)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Nice perspective corrections
glLineWidth(2.0f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrongly set the texture object to the texture sampler uniform. This is wrong:

> ```cpp
> glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(worldShaderProgram, "texAtlas"), testTexture);
> ```

The binding point between the texture object and the texture sampler uniform is the texture unit. When [`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml) is invoked, then the texture object is bound to the specified target and the current texture unit. The texture unit can be chosen by [`glActivTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml). The default texture unit is `GL_TEXTURE0`.

Since your texture is bound to texture unit 0 (`GL_TEXTURE0`), you have set the value 0 to the texture sampler uniform:

```cpp
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(worldShaderProgram, "texAtlas"), 0);
```

Note that your code worked before by chance. You just had 1 texture object or `testTexture` was the first texture name created. Hence the value of `testTexture` was 0. Now the value of `testTexture` is no longer 0, causing your code to fail.